# Transform App.Config in unit test

Tags: app-config, config-transformation

I am using slowcheetah transformation and the transformation works fine.

On TeamCity I want my unittest to build my code in release mode and use the app.config from the debug build. In other words how can I

1. Build my app in release mode.
2. Build debug config file
3. overwrite app.release.config with app.debug.config.

It's all boils down to trigger the transformation in code.